# App crashes when trying to add SKNode from if statement

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, sknode

I'm trying to create a moving background on top of a still background using a `NSTimer`, it works fine until I call the command to add another child. Here is the error I'm getting.

- `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attemped to add a SKNode which already has a parent: <SKSpriteNode> name:'(null)' texture:[<SKTexture> 'groundGrass.png' (53 x 71)] position:{159, 35} size:{808, 71}`

Here is my code to move the ground:

```
-(void)moveGroundGrass{

groundGrass.position = CGPointMake(groundGrass.position.x -1, groundGrass.position.y);

if (groundGrass.position.x < 160){

    [self addChild:groundGrass];
}
```

Here is the rest:

```
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {

if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
    /* Setup your scene here */

    SKSpriteNode *background = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"background"];
    background.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));

    background.xScale = 0.9;
    background.yScale = 1.1837f;


    [self addChild:background];


    groundGrass = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"groundGrass"];

    groundGrass.position = CGPointMake (404, 35);

    [self addChild:groundGrass];

    moveGround = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01f target:self selector:@selector(moveGroundGrass) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];


       }
return self;
```

}

When groundGrass.png moves past the point on screen where it is supposed to add another child node, it crashes...

Answer (score 2):

You arent creating a new `groundGrass` in the `moveGroundGrass` method. You need to create a new one like you did in the `initWithSize:`

In an Obj-C you create an object like this: `object *name [object new];` where `object` can be f.e. UIView.

If you want to have easy access to the objects you are creating you can add them into an `NSMutableArray` but if you only want to add them and then do nothing to them(not recommended) you can just create it and then add it to the view.

Comment: So how to I create a new groundGrass, I though thats what [self addChild:groundGrass]; did or how do I add a child node to the parent node if that makes any sense.... sure i could just make a groundGrass2 but i'd rather not do that if possible is there a a command that would be anything like [self addSubChild:groundGrass];?

Comment: you think you can give me an example using my code to add another node to generate once groundGrass.x passes 160, your explanation is probably correct but im having trouble understanding/implementing it.

Comment: Like I said object *name [object new]; but in your case you would rename object to SKSpriteNode because that is the object you are using.

Comment: Yea, but when i do that here is what happens, when groundGrass passes the coordinates 160, every 0.01 seconds a child node is added... instead of it adding a new node every 0.01 seconds (NSTimer moveGround) how can i make it only add it once, once it passes that point, and not every 0.01 seconds?

Comment: I think you can figure it out yourself actually.

Comment: If I could do that would I have asked for help? I know it has to do with the timer which would be why it spams out new nodes every 0.01 seconds but my issue is how can i get this to happen separate from the timer.... ive made a mockup in a new app without sprite-kit using UIImageView instead, and it doesn't do this so im not sure whats going on....